# Is there a simple way to allow a thrid party to add content to my website?

Tags: html, iframe, feed

I am currently creating a basic website for a small sports-association. It is simply used to display some basic information about training times, becoming a member, locations, history, etc...

However, we would also like the option to add news and upcoming special events. I am making the website in HTML, but this is much too complex for the other volunteers. I was wondering if I could embed some service into the website where they can easily add some small news articles without diving into html.

I myself was first thinking of using some simple blog-service (like notion.so, blogger.com) and embedding this using an IFrame. However, most websites have a protection against being used as a frame.

I would like at some point that they do not rely on me for basic updates. Is there a way to implement this option? Or should we fall back on something like google sites?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the company. I suggest asking them if they would like to add content first, and if they say no, I think thats copyright.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using google sites because the viewers of the website can always scroll dow and find out this is through Google Sites. In my opinion that doesn't seem as professional.

My answer is to teach them the basics. It isn't that hard to teach them that the text goes inside

and a header is  through

Answer (score 0):

I now found out it is possible to embed a blogger.com page in an iFrame, so this is a solution for now.